# Uso do Jquery em uma página PHP é possível?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

Tenho uma página de Login, na qual tem um formulário, que envia os dados de dois campos (nome de usuário e senha) para um arquivo PHP que faz a verificação. Esse arquivo php se utiliza de uma função já escrita em uma classe. Nessa função, caso o resultado seja true, acontece um redirecionamento, caso não seja, ele vai executar um código Jquery para apresentar uma mensagem de "Senha inválida" lá ná pagina de login. A intenção é que esse Jquery mude a propriedade de um certo elemento de "hidden" para "visible", apresentando assim a mensagem na tela.

Estou meio confuso, e nunca mexi direito com jQuery, nem sei se estou esquecendo algum detalhe importante, então gostaria que uma boa alma me desse um help.Segue os códigos
HTML:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1", true);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login_style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="login-page">
            <div class="form">
                <form class="login-form" action="verificacaologin.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" name="nome_usuario"/>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" name="senha"/>
                    <button type="submit">login</button>
                </form>
                <label class="senha_incorreta">Senha incorreta.Tente novamente.</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Php que faz a verificação:

```
<?php
include_once 'classes/Usuario.php';

$nome = $_POST['nome_usuario'];
$senh = $_POST['senha'];

$usuario = new Usuario();

$usuario->verificarExistenciaLogin( $nome , $senh);
?>
```

Function da classe Usuario que contem o Jquery:

```
public function verificarSenhaCorreta( $nome_usuario , $senha )
{
    $query = "select SENHA from portfolio.usuario where NOME_USUARIO = '$nome_usuario' ";
    $conexao = new Conexao();
    $resultado_consulta = $conexao->abrirConexao( $query );

    $resultado_consulta = implode($resultado_consulta);

    if( $resultado_consulta == $senha )
    { 

          header("Location:ordem_servico.php");
    }
    else
    {
        //mostrar mensagem de que a senha está incorreta();

        ?>
        //Aqui que minhas dúvidas começam
        <script>

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('.senha_incorreta').css( "visibility" , "visible" );
        });

        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Não existe "página PHP". O PHP pode até gerar uma página, mas depois de enviada para o cliente ela é igual a qualquer outra. Entretanto, já que no PHP você tem controle sobre o que vai ser enviado, faz muito mais sentido mandar já a informação correta para o usuário. EVENTUALMENTE dá pra carregar os dados via AJAX ou qualquer outro método interativo, mas isso independe de que técnica vai usar no JS (se é JS puro, se é jQuery, ou seja lá o que escolher)..

Comment: PHP é script que além de outras funcionalidades, gera o HTML que por sua vez pode importar ou ter Javascript

Comment: Pelo que vi no seu código você não referenciou o arquivo **JQuery** dentro do **HTML**. Acredito que quando fizer isso irá funcionar, senão, tenta fazer a consulta através do evento `onclick()` do `button` utilizando o **Ajax** que irá aguardar a resposta do **PHP** e assim habilitar ou desabilitar a **label**.

Answer (score 1):

**Bom dia. Sim é possivél. Talvez isso possa ajudá-lo:**

```
//Codigo PHP
public function verificarSenhaCorreta( $nome_usuario , $senha )
{
  $query = "select SENHA from portfolio.usuario where NOME_USUARIO = '$nome_usuario' ";
  $conexao = new Conexao();
  $resultado_consulta = $conexao->abrirConexao( $query );

  $resultado_consulta = implode($resultado_consulta);

  if( $resultado_consulta == $senha )
  { 

      header("Location:ordem_servico.php");
  }
  else
  {
    //mostrar mensagem de que a senha está incorreta();
    echo "<script>functionHideMessage();</script>"
  }
}

//Codigo HTML, faca um 'style display:none' pra ocultar <label>
<label class="senha_incorreta" style="display:none;">Senha incorreta.Tente novamente.</label>

//Codigo Jquery fora do PHP
//Se lembra de chamar a libreria Jquery
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       function functionHideMessage(){
          //Com o '.show()', removemos a propiedade 'display:none' e o conteudo do <label> fica visível
          $('.senha_incorreta').show();
       }           
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Te contar o que?

Comment: Tudo bem, eu só queria saber se a resposta foi útil para ele ou se eu poderia ajudá-lo com outra coisa.

Comment: Então, vou te dar uma dica, não leve isso como crítica negativa. Para a sua resposta ser útil para outros usuários seria legal você descrever o que fez pra resolver o problema e o motivo pelo qual você acha que o erro estava acontecendo. Fica bem mais didático

Comment: Ok, tudo bem. Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma função fora do PHP, juntamente com seu php, nesse molde:

```
<body>
    ... conteudos php, html e etc
    <script>
        function exibeMensagemErro() {
            $('.senha_incorreta').css( "visibility" , "visible" );
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

e no seu else, faça:

```
echo "<script>exibeMensagemErro()</script>";
```